# Python: нужно парсить JSON с лишней запятой

Tags: python, json, парсер

Такой код:

```
import json
s = '{ "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", }'
json.loads(s)
```

Вызывает следующую ошибку в Python 2:

> ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 16 (char 15)

Аналогично в Python 3:

> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 16 (char 15)

Конечно, если убрать запятую после последнего значения в словаре, то ошибки не будет. Но как обрабатывать JSON именно с запятой в конце словаря или списка? Это ведь мелочь, к тому же, JavaScript такое позволяет.

<sub>Например, такая задача может возникнуть в админ-консоли для быстрого ручного редактирования настроек, когда удаляешь последнюю запись – хотелось бы не напрягать юзера поиском иголки в стоге сена и правильным проставлением какой-то запятой.</sub>

Перевод [этого вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52636846/5308802).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что [официальный стандарт JSON](http://www.json.org) предполагает некорректным наличие лишней запятой в конце списка или словаря, поэтому официальные парсеры будут ругаться на такую мелочь. Возможные решения:

#### 1) "Починить" формат убрав лишний символ с помощью RegEx

Чиним:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '{ "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", }'
>>> re.sub(r"\"\s*,\s*\}", "\" }", s)
'{ "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2" }'
```

Парсим:

```
>>> import json
>>> s2 = re.sub(r"\"\s*,\s*\}", "\" }", s)
>>> json.loads(s2)
{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
```

Но у этого метода есть важный **недостаток**, в определённых случаях он может испортить строку. Пример такой строки: `{ "foo": ",}" }`

#### 2) Использовать другой парсер

Есть такие альтернативы стандартному модулю `json`:

- [json5](https://pypi.org/project/json5/) – реализация [стандарта JSON5](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSON5). Позволяет использовать одно- и многострочные комментарии, многострочные строки, строки не только с `"`, но и с `'`, а также запятые в конце списков/словарей.
- [jsoncomment](https://pypi.org/project/jsoncomment/) – функционал в целом такой же, но модуль кажется не поддерживаемым и упомянут чисто в академических целях.

У этого способа тоже есть важный **недостаток**: к сожалению, сторонние библиотеки работают в десятки и сотни раз медленнее стандартного модуля, они сами это признают. Поэтому к выбору способа решения проблемы придётся подходить продуманно.

<sub>Перевод [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52636881/5308802), [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52636919/5308802) и [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52636861/5308802) ответов.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Есть один dirty hack:

```
>>> s = '{ "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", }'
>>> res=str(eval(s)).replace('\'', '"')
>>> res
'{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}'
>>> json.loads(res)
{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
>>>
```

Comment: В принципе, рабочий вариант :) С одной стороны, это будет уязвимостью, т.к позволяет юзверю исполнять любой код (в каком-то языки, не помню точно, есть две такие команды: одна исполняет любой код, а другая только вычисления). А с другой — JSON действительно близок синтаксису Питона; интересно, насколько (является ли его подмножеством?), и как поведёт себя такое решение в более сложных ситуациях?

Comment: Можно было в один шаг сделать:  `eval` и так преобразовал строку в словарь. Зачем опять перегонять в строку, чтобы с помощью `json.loads` опять перегнать строку в словарь? Ну и чтобы безопасно было, можно вместо `eval` использовать `ast.literal_eval`, результат будет тот же, но без возможности исполнения произвольного python кода.

Comment: @AivanF. ну так я потому и написал, что это dirty hack - eval всегда нужно использовать с осторожностью.

Comment: @insolor вообще, этот код использовался просто для "починки" словаря и приведения его к каноническому виду json. А jason.loads здесь просто потому, что таков был вопрос.

Comment: @strawdog, это смотря как интерпретировать вопрос. Если нужно просто распарсить такой json, а не починить, то можно просто `ast.literal_eval` использовать без промежуточного преобразования в json.